# How to intensionally drop packets in NS2 for particular node in WSN

Tags: networking, tcl, ns2

I need to simulate failed sensor node in WSN which will drop the packets which are routed to it in AODV protocol. I am using Ns2.35.

Can any one please help.

[Simulating packet dropping in a wireless network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261983/simulating-packet-dropping-in-a-wireless-network)
[packet dropping in ns2][1]

I tried with malicious node packet drop, but this is not working.

< [1]: [Simulating packet dropping in a wireless network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261983/simulating-packet-dropping-in-a-wireless-network) >

Comment: What do you mean with "this is not working"?

Comment: I tried with the implementation suggested in the below link, and packets are not been dropped.